Animate modal to resize with no set height values
I have a modal window that comes up from the bottom of the page when a button is clicked. It will have a form inside of it but doesnt currently. It just has a div within with a large top and bottom margin as a placeholder.
When the submit button is clicked, it removes that div and replaces it with another div that is much smaller in height (like a notification or alert). Both divs are contained inside the modal div.
It resizes afterwards since the contents divs are different sizes but it does so very abruptly after the change happens. I want it to animate to the smaller size. But neither div has a set height property, it expands based on the contents within them.
<div class="quote">
    <div class="exit"></div>
    <div class="quoteForm">Form</div>
    <div class="quoteAlert">
        Thank you for your inquiry.
    </div>
    <div class="submit"></div>
</div>

.quote {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  /*height: 300px;*/
  width: 100%;
  background: #9900ff;
  transform: translateY(800px);
  transition: transform .2s ease;
  opacity: .95;
}

.quote.active {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: transform .2s ease;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exit span {
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin-top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit span:before {
  width: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 2px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: -4px;
  display: block;
}

.exit.active {
  display: none;
}



.submit {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 27px;
  right: 33px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submit span {
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.submit span:before {
  width: 10px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: -4px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.submit span:after {
  width: 10px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 2px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 4px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.submit.active span {
  display: none;
}

.quoteForm {
  color: #fafafa;
  /*display: block;*/
  padding: 90px 0 90px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform .9s ease;
}

.quoteAlert {
  color: #fafafa;
  /*display: block;*/
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform .9s ease;
}

function send(){
    $('.exit').toggleClass('active');
    $('.submit').toggleClass('active');
    $('.quoteForm').fadeOut(0);
    $('.quoteAlert').fadeIn(0);
    $('.quote').delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
}

I've tried putting transition tags in the css in every class i think would affect that and nothing has worked to make the height of the modal animate as it shrinks. It animates fine as it is sliding into view and out of view. just not the resizing of it.

An animation/transition requires start and end values. If you can't define them you can't transition to them. It sounds at though you just pop the form in but that can' be transitioned.

See i thought of just going that route myself and just making the alert in another modal window and animating it into view the same way I did the first one but possibly after I get the form made out and styled how i want it i can find a height value for the original modal window and then the same for the alert and get it to animate I am just trying to prototype the design out using placeholders at the moment.

I'm not sure why you are replacing divs etc when you could just be hiding/showing them instead. Then you don't need to worry about popping them in/out. Then you can animate them with slideUp/Down (I assume you are using JQ).

I assumed hiding and showing them was what it was doing. Are you referring to using .show and .hide instead of .fadeIn and .fadeOut ?

You mentioned removing and adding elements rather than showing/hiding. So instead of fading or just showing, why not slide one up and the other down afterwards or something like that?. An [mcve] would be useful.

I figured it out.
I took your advice Paulie_D and created a second modal that is just the alert to slide in after the form slides out. Then using a setTimeout, I was able to get the proper animations I was looking for without hiding anything.
